# Magento 2 REST - Add sku to items on /totals API response

Tags: rest, api, magento2

I'm creating a basic shop using the Magento 2 API. The main goal of this question is to fill the mini-cart with a SINGLE API-Call, but there is none that returns cart totals AND all necessary item fields like sku and url_key. The endpoint I'm currently using is:

> /rest/V1/guest-carts/[..]/totals

This is the response:

```
Array
(
   [grand_total] => 62.9
   [base_grand_total] => 62.9
   [..]
   [items]=> Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 523
                [price] => 62.9
                [sku] => MISSING!
                [url_key] => MISSING! 
                [..]
```

How can I add **sku** and **url_key** to the items array?

What I've found so far:

- The Interface responsible is:

  > vendor\magento\module-quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemInterface.php
- There are extension attributes: (But I don't really find a way to make it happen with that)

  > http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you find any solution for this ?